# Why `queryObjects()` in chrome console returns undefined but then results are printed out?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I executed the function `queryObjects(WebSocket.prototype)` in chrome console, which was promised to return an array of existing websockets on that page. However the return value is `undefined`, then after a while the expected result was printed out. What happens?

```
> queryObjects(WebSocket.prototype)
< undefined
  Array(1)
  ...
```

It seems that this function has no return value but just prints out the query result.

Comment: That's quite strange... So is there any way to get the query results as a variable?

Comment: you can always right-click the logged array and then select "store as global variable"

Comment: In console I can right-click the printed value and choose "Store object as global variable", so the array can be saved as a temporary variable(possibly named `temp1`). That's my goal and now the question is, can this be done by code?